# Determine parameter so that the absolute value of real solution of the equation is larger than the modulo of complex solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

Given the equation:
$$x^3+x+\lambda=0$$
determine real parameter $\lambda$ so that the real solution is greater by absolute value than modulo of the complex solutions. 
My attempt:
Let $x_1$ be the real root and $x_2 = a+ib$ one of the complex roots. Then the third root is $x_3=a-ib$. From here, by using Vieta's formulas we have:
$$x_1 + a+ib+a-ib =x_1+2a= 0$$
$$x_1(a+ib) + x_1(a-ib) + a^2 +b^2 = 2ax_1 + a^2 + b^2  = 1$$
$$x_1(a^2+b^2) = -\lambda$$
but i seem to be stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_1=-2a\quad=>\quad b^2=3a^2+1\quad=>\quad\lambda=2a(4a^2+1).$$

Comment: Well that's obvious but how do i find $\lambda$ values satisfying task requirements ? :D

Comment: @Irrational: $|x_1|>|x_{2,3}|\iff|2a|>\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{4a^2+1}\iff4a^2>4a^2+1\iff$ There are no solutions.